# Rename tag [eulers-constant] to [euler-mascheroni-constant]

Tags: discussion, tagging

[It](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553909/53846) [seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553843/53846) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520869/53846) the name *Euler's constant*, used to denote the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$, is often interpreted as [Euler's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) $e$. To avoid ambiguity, I propose that the tag [eulers-constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eulers-constant) be renamed to [euler-mascheroni-constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-mascheroni-constant).

Comment: Seems like half of the questions talk about $e$ and half talk about $\gamma$. I think we can just merge it into one of the other tags, e.g. [tag:constants].

Comment: BTW the tag ([tag:e]) is [synonym of](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/exponential-function/synonyms) ([tag:exponential-function]).

Comment: @Martin: I think we should place a ban on one-letter tag names in general.

Comment: Perhaps ([tag:eulers-number]) could be a reasonably synonym of ([tag:e]). (Or replacement, should one-letter tag be removed.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hm, is *pi* a one-letter tag name?

Comment: @Hagen: No, it has two letters. π would have been one letter.

Comment: pi may not be a one-letter tag name but it certainly is one letter tag name.